# fulltrustprocesslauncher does not exist in current context

Tags: powershell, uwp

I am trying to figure out how to execute a powershell script from my uwp desktop application. I think I am sort of going in the right direction but need a bit of help. I am getting "The name FullTrustProcessLauncher does not exist in the current context". I have checked the references and I have the Windows Desktop extensions for the UWP.

Can someone help thanks

**Mainpage.xaml**

```
   private async void doSomething(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await  FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
    }
```

**package manifest**

```
 <Applications>
<Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="ProjectCuwp.App">
<Extensions
xmlns:desktop="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10">
<desktop:Extension
  Category="windows.fullTrustProcess"
  Executable="powershell.exe" />
```

**References installed:**
Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP

Answer (score 4):

I needed to add:

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
```

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know what else to say. The answer was to add using Windows.ApplicationModel; If anybody can explain what I am supposed to say I would greatly appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: I was just missing the references. In the solution explorer, in the UWP project, right click `References -> Add Reference` and search for `Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP`, add it and it shows up. Hope i can help some others that had the same issue as i did